# How do I wrap this function call

Tags: javascript

I am looking at [this tutorial](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2013/09/27/introduction-to-actions-in-crm-2013.aspx) and the author assumes some piece of knowledge that I must not have.

They state this is the javascript code:

```
if (typeof (SDK) == "undefined")
    ........snipped for brevity see full code at tutorial link
};
```

and then they say you can call it with:

```
  SDK.Action.ApproveRequest(salesOrderId, approvedById);
```

What is eluding me is don't I have to wrap the "chunk" of javascript code in some function wrapper to be able to call it....or can you just put random javascript in a js file and somehow it works?

Also my title is weak and I will update it with better keywords if you have any suggestions.

TIA

Comment: Are you talking about the second code block in your question? If that is placed below the `if` statement, it'll just execute like any other part of the application. You only need to put code in a function when you want to explicitly invoke it at a particular moment.

Comment: Yes....see my comment to @quentin. I didn't realize you could have statements outside of a wrapping function...shows how little I know.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/contents.html might be worth a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can you just put random javascript in a js file and somehow it works?

Yes. JS in a JS file is interpreted when loaded via a script element.

If the JS includes a function declaration, it is interpreted as "Here is a function!".

Other kinds of expressions are also interpreted.

If that wasn't the case then it would be impossible to call any function (other then via intrinsic event attributes).

Comment: so...for my understanding I can have if statements etc. without being enclosed in a function. Interesting new concept for me.